# Complex structures on topological surfaces

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, surfaces

1. I am interested in the number of complex structures on a surface. More precisely, given a genus $g$ surface (topological manifold of real dimension 2) with $n$ punctures $X_{(g,n)}$, how many complex structures (up to biholomorphic maps) are there? The usual answer I can find online are for those without punctures.
2. Also, is there any formula that describes the size of $[X_{(g,n)} , X_{(g',n')}]$, which is defined to be the set of all holomorphic maps (up to biholomorphic maps)
   $$
   \mbox{i.e. } \mbox{Aut}(X_{(g,n)})\backslash \mbox{ Holo}(X_{(g,n)},X_{(g',n')}) \,/ \mbox{Aut}(X_{(g',n')}),
   $$
   from the left to the right?

Comment: Is not $\dim \mathcal{M}_{g, \, n}$ known? In genus $\geq 2$ the general curve has finite automorphism group (and trivial automorphism group for $g \geq 3$) so the dimension is $3g-3+n$.

Comment: I am not familiar with this field.. would you mind pointing out some reference?

Answer (score 6):

The number is one if $g=0, n\leq 3$ and infinite in all other cases. The set of complex structures is a singular manifold which is called the moduli space and its complex dimension is $1$ when $g=1, n=0$, and 
$3g-3+n$ in all other cases. A good reference is

W. Abikoff, The real analytic theory of Teichmuller space, Springer 1980.